How to use the echo command to display /? without it showing its own help information
I am writing a batch script featuring a help screen containing this echo string:
echo   /?                      Show this screen

How would I prevent the echo command, in this case, from printing its own help output?
I already tried inserting a zero width character (U+200B, U+200C and U+200D), but Windows is not a big fan of displaying them, (probably due to a lack of unicode support).
I attempted ^/? as well as /^? and / ?, all still showing `echo``s help instead.
I attempted writing into a file, and then printing from there, using type, or simmilar, until I noticed only echo could put arbitrary data into files.

The DosTips forum topic ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/ explains that echo( is best to output an empty line or a line with other text like /? without any file system access in comparison to echo. and nothing else or a text to output which always results in a file system access for searching for a file with name echo in the current directory (and executing it if there is indeed a file echo in the current directory).

You have to replace the space character,  , immediately following echo with a period, .:
echo   /?                      Show this screen

becomes:
echo.  /?                      Show this screen


You can also use a : or a ( instead of a . if you want.

The less "strange" way is: echo/   /?. Don't use echo.   /?, it is much slower than echo/   /?
